# How to prove a Hamming distance as a Kernel?

Tags: self-study, kernel-trick

> Given Hamming distance $H(x,z)$ between two equal length string of length $n$, define a kernel as:
>
> $$
> K(x,z) = \begin{cases}
> 1 - \frac{H(x,z)}{n} & \text{if both x and z have the same length $n$}
> \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

**Question:** How do I prove that it is a kernel?

**Attempt:** It is symmetric for sure, but proving positive semi-definite would involve proving $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i K(x_i, x_j) \alpha_j \ge 0$$ for all sets of strings $\{x_i\}$ and vectors $\alpha$, and I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1.** For an arbitrary set of strings $\{x_i\}$, first sort them by their length. Then the kernel matrix is block-diagonal, since the kernel value between any two strings of different lengths is zero.
This lets us see that we only need to consider strings of the same length; how?

**Step 2.** So, we only need to consider a set of strings $\{ x_i \}$ all of length $m$. Then we can see that $$K(x, z) = \frac1m \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{1}(x_i = z_i), \tag{*}$$
where $\mathbb{1}(x_i = z_i)$ is 1 if $x_i = z_i$, 0 otherwise.

Looking at it this way lets us find an explicit feature map from the space of strings of length $m$ to vectors of a certain length: that is, $K(x, z) = \varphi(x)^T \varphi(z)$, for some function $\varphi$. Do you see what that function is?

*Hint:* if $a = (0, 1, 0, 1)$ and $b = (1, 1, 0, 0)$, then $a^T b = 0 + 1 + 0 + 0$; in general, for length-$k$ vectors whose entries are all either $0$ or $1$, $a^T b = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i b_i = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb 1(a_i = 1, b_i = 1)$. So you might want to come up with some function $\varphi$ that turns this into something that looks like (*).

**Step 3.** From there, it's a standard result that we have positive definiteness pretty quickly. Supposing that $\varphi$ maps into $\mathbb R^k$, let $\Phi$ be the $n \times k$ matrix whose $i$th row is $\varphi(x_i)$, so that $(\Phi \Phi^T)_{ij} = \varphi(x_i)^T \varphi(x_j) = K(x_i, x_j)$. Then the psd condition is that for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i K(x_i, x_j) a_j = a^T K a = a^T \Phi \Phi^T a = (\Phi^T a)^T (\Phi^T a) = \lVert \Phi^T a \rVert^2 \ge 0
.$$

Comment: A pretty big hint for step 1, if you don't see it, is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/prove-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix-are-the-combined-eigenvalues-of-its).

Comment: How do you find the explicit feature map?

Comment: Think about the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1n \mathbb{1}(x_i = z_i)$, and how you could factor that into some vectors for each of $x$ and $z$ that have that inner product.

Comment: sorry could not understand. what does $1(x_i = z_i)$ mean?

Comment: It's notation that means put a 1 there if $x_i = z_i$, 0 if not. So $K(x, z)$ is just the portion of entries that are the same.

Comment: I understand how it is 1 for $x_i = z_i$, since the hamming distance will be 0, but what for the other strings whose lengths match?

Comment: What happens to $K$ when only one entry is different, so $H(x, z) = 1$? What about for two? $n-1$?

Comment: yeah i guess, as per hamming distance. Like H("abc","zbx") would be 2

Comment: it would be great. I am still figuring out how to do this

Comment: but, the vectors will not have either 1 or 0, it will have values 0>x>1 as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56135/discussion-between-dougal-and-koustuv-sinha).