# Prove strictly positive-definite kernel

Tags: kernel-trick

It can be shown that the Hamming distance defines a positive semi-definite kernel (see e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270181/how-to-prove-a-hamming-distance-as-a-kernel)). However, is the kernel
$$ K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}\{x_i = y_i\}$$
*strictly* positive-definite? That is, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $c_1,\dots, c_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots, \mathbf{x}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j k(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j) > 0. $$

Moreover, is the kernel defined by $\exp\{K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})\}$ *strictly* positive-definite?

Comment: The real Hilbert wouldn't have to get on here and ask such trivial questions.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Agreed; but your comment does not answer the question whether the kernel defined by $\exp\{K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\}$ is strictly positive-definite?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone If you claim this question as "trivial", please offer an answer; if you decline to offer help, I wonder why you are active on this platform in the first place...